# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 338742]

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessClassifier
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF
import cv2

input = "testProbe.jpg"
# load the image, convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread(input)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# threshold the image to reveal light regions in the gray image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 145, 200, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# import data
X = np.where(thresh>0)
widthX = len(X[0])
y = np.asarray(np.zeros((widthX, 1), dtype=int))

gpc_rbf_isotropic = GaussianProcessClassifier().fit(X, y)
```

And I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 338742]
```

What am I doing wrong with y? I think y is the problem, but I do not understand what it is exactly doing.

In this [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpc_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-gaussian-process-plot-gpc-iris-py) they used two different kind of datasets. I want to use only one dataset.

Can anyone help?

*(I know there are other topics with a similar topic, but it didn't helped me.)*

Comment: what is the shape of `X` ? Do you have 338742 samples ? `y` should contain the class labels

Comment: @seralouk thank you for your answer. I found my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I know where my problem was now. For one thing, y wasn't the problem, it was X.
That's how it worked:

```
xx = np.array(X)
xx = np.ravel(xx,order='F')
X = xx.reshape((int(len(xx)/2),2))
y = np.asarray(np.zeros((widthX, 1), dtype=int))
gpc_rbf_isotropic = GaussianProcessClassifier().fit(X, y)
```

The other thing is, this funktion isn't working for only one dataset.